# How can standardize the view mode of my Website?

Tags: size, screen-orientation

I'm developing my website, but I'm having a little problem. On my computer I can see the site like I want, but when I see in my notebook, a content is very to right! In my computer is normal. I'll have the site for you to see. It's in Portuguese, because I'm Brazilian. But please give a look at the source code. Or better, I will pass the code for you. The CLASS of the content of the right is: content-inner-jogo-destaque
And this is the code:
CSS:

```
.content-inner-jogo-destaque
{
position:absolute;
top:15px;
right:15px;
width:200px;
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 10px 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #1f325d;
-o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #1f325d;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #1f325d;
-ms-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #1f325d;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #1f325d;
border-left: 3px solid #eeeeee;
border-right: 3px solid #eeeeee;
border-bottom: 3px solid #eeeeee;
border-top: 3px solid #eeeeee;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class='content-inner-jogo-destaque'>
<p>Jogo da semana:</p>
<a href="testando"><img src="imagens/semana1.jpg" title="Clique para ir para a 
p&aacute;gina do jogo da semana" style="width:200px"/></a>
<font size="3"><font face="verdana,geneva">Dragon Ball Z Budo<font size="3">kai Tenkaichi 3</font></font></font>
</div>
</body>
```

Well, here is the site: [www.ganggames.p.ht](http://www.ganggames.p.ht)
Please take a look and tell me if something wrong.
Can I use CSS to change the pixels of the site?
Or a metatag?
Can you help me?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 things for you:

**1)** I think the main reason why your content is showing up on the right side of you page is because your content is set to "position: absolute" then you are telling it to stay 15px from the right of the page. That means that no matter how big or small your screen is, that DIV will ALWAYS be 15px from the right of the page.

You can keep the code you currently have if you wrap all of your content in a DIV with a set width:

```
<head>
    <style>#wrapper {width: 'whatever-your-content-width-is';}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!--ALL OF YOUR CONTENT-->
    </div>
</body>
```

You can also now neatly center all of your content if you would like with *(optional)*:

```
<style>body {text-align: center;}</style>
```

**2)** For cross device compatibility, it is the standard for helping with viewing issues is this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Further research of that tag can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

**3)** Double check all of your BODY, HEAD, FOOTER, etc, tags! They aren't executed properly.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the body and head tags are not totally correct because I use this to include the menu and default content of the site in all pages: <?php include("includes/padrao.php");?>
The file padrao contains the default content to be displayed in all pages of the site. So, the body and head will don't match. Please, take a look in the source code of my site. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh okay, I overlooked PHP. Hope that the rest of it made sense though!